# How to solve Fatal error: Index out of range in Xcode Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, xcode11

I was wondering why this code says index out of range

Specific problem code:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = contactsAry[indexPath.row]
```

Whole code having issues:

```
extension ContactsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return (myContact.count + contactsAry.count)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
         if indexPath.row < myContact.count {
            let contact = myContact[indexPath.row]
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainUsersAccount") as!
            ContactsLayout
            
            cell.setContacts(contacts: contact)
            
            return cell

        } else {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "UserItem")
        cell.textLabel?.text = contactsAry[indexPath.row]

        return cell
        }
    }
```

This is my array "contactsAry" `let contactsAry = ["Brandon", "Luisa"]`

MainUserAccount setting code:

```
    func createArray() -> [Contacts] {
        var tempContact: [Contacts] = []
        
        let userName = "Temp User"
        
        let myContact = Contacts(UserIcon: UIImage(systemName: "\(userName.prefix(1).lowercased()).circle.fill")!, UserName: userName, MyAccountLabel: "My Account")
        
        tempContact.append(myContact)
        
        return tempContact
    }
```

I have two different prototype cells trying to be added to the same tableView. The first cell which is basically just a users account cell is identified as "MainUserAccount" and it's just one cell that can have it's icon and name changed. The second cell is identified as "UserItem" which is basically just a list of users that you have added to your "friends list". Im unsure why I keep getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full error code I get in console:

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift,
> line 444 2020-08-02 03:04:18.896635-0700 Schedule[44839:2131710] Fatal
> error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift,
> line 444

Comment: `contactsAry` does not have enough values ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to remove the count of precious array ... otherwise it will try to access 3rd instance rather then 0

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "UserItem")
        cell.textLabel?.text = contactsAry[indexPath.row - myContact.count]
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! The error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift,
> line 444 2020-08-02 03:04:18.896635-0700 Schedule[44839:2131710] Fatal
> error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift,
> line 444

just basically means that you are accessing an array index but that index is greater than the max index of an array.

---

As you already know, accessing an array starts from 0.
Getting the index from an `IndexPath` is through `row` or `item`, and `section`.
The way you get the max index of an array is through the count of your data array minus 1.

---

From what I can see, like what you mentioned, you have two different kinds of cells. The way you handle it in your `cellForRow` might be right, but the value you are passing to `numberOfRowsInSection` is too much, you are combining the count of your both arrays.

`return (myContact.count + contactsAry.count)`

The sum - 1 will be the max `indexPath.row` your tableView will try to access, hence the crash (out of range).

---

One way to solve this is utilize the section. For instance, you could do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == 0 {
        return myContact.count
    } else {
        return contactsAry.count
    }
}
```

and for that, you need another method `numberOfSections`.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

And from there, handle the sections and rows the same way in your `cellForRow`. You can take it from here.

Comment: This one helped me to put both of the contents up at the same time, however im still having issues with displaying the full content. Also thank you for welcoming me. :D